# Identifying and comparing syntactic structure of questio-sentence

Tags: nlp, analytics, nltk, semantics

I am getting question from user and trying to understand syntactically.

My goal is to identify the exact question sentence from user entered question. Like

```
Obama is president of USA, who is his wife?
```

So I am able to apply `anaphora resolution` and get `his` pointing to `Obama` and can convert above sentence to

```
   Obama is president of USA, who is Obama wife?
```

but how can I syntactically identify exact question sentence i.e. `Who is obama wife?` from above entire question

I am trying with `pylinkgrammar` which give 54 linkage for above sentence, like

```
linkparser> 
    Linkage 54, cost vector = (UNUSED=0 DIS= 8.05 LEN=24)

    +------------------------------Xp------------------------------+
    +---------------------->WV---------------------->+             |
    +-------------------Xx-------------------+-->WV->+---SIs---+   |
    +----Wd---+--Ss--+--Oum--+---Mp--+-Js+   +Wq+--Q-+   +Ds**c+   |
    |         |      |       |       |   |   |  |    |   |     |   |
LEFT-WALL Obama[!] is.v president.t of USA.l , who is.v his wife.n ?
```

What I want to do it defining pattern for different question type like W5H1, conjunction based question etc.

But I dont find how to write rule for these pattern, any suggestion and reference would be much appreciable?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extract different possible sub-questions (hypotheses) from your original text and test for textual entailment between your text and hypotheses. Check out http://hltfbk.github.io/Excitement-Open-Platform/#Recognizing_Textual_Entailment